# SQL finding out the common values in two tables

Tags: sql

I have two tables as `vMerkmale` and `aREL_Adr_Merk`. They have one common attribute as `MID`. I want to bind `Mtitel` from `merkmale` whose  `MID`'s are common with `aREl_Adr_Merk`. BUT , the problem is that , when I choose two IDs then it binds all values of these two IDs. I JUST WANT  TO Bind their common  MTITEL Values. MY code is below..

```
   SELECT M.mtitel as Attribute FROM vMerkmale  M ,aREL_Adr_Merk R
   where m.mid=R.MID and AdrID in(252674,247354) 
   group by M.MTitel
```

Comment: what do you mean by bind? can you explain the problem clearly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
select distinct M.mtitel as Attribute
from merkmale as M
where M.MID in (
    select A.MID 
    from aREl_Adr_Merk as A 
    where A.AdrID in (252674,247354)
)
```

[**SQL FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c427a/1)

Comment: It gave the same result. There is just one common value. But it gives the all values without repeating. For example. The values of in Merkmale are ; 1,2,3,5,6,7  in aRel_Adr_Merk ; 1,2,3,4,8 then it gives me 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8  BUT, I want 1,2,3

Comment: well then I can say that I cannot understand what you want to get as a result.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that , when I choose two IDs then it binds all values
> of these two IDs. I JUST WANT TO Bind their common MTITEL Values

Use `DISTINCT` with a `JOIN` on the common attribute `MID` like what you did in your query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT M.mtitel as Attribute 
FROM vMerkmale  M 
INNER JOIN aREL_Adr_Merk R ON m.mid = R.MID
WHERE m.AdrID in(252674, 247354)
```

### [Demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/83500)

Comment: It gave the same result. There is just one common value. But it gives the all values without repeating. For example. The values of in Merkmale are ; 1,2,3,5,6,7 in aRel_Adr_Merk ; 1,2,3,4,8 then it gives me 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 BUT, I want 1,2,3

Comment: @Isi This is what it did see [**this demo**](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/83500). It should work like his check your syntax again.

Comment: I checked it, everything is looking correct, but after the executing it gives the both table's values.

Comment: Can you please post the two table structures, sample data, the exact query you are using, and it would  be great if you could setup a demo in SQL Fiddle or in  data.stackexchange.com

Comment: my query is the just same with the fiddle.

Comment: @Isi - Did you select `DISTINCT mtitel` or `DISTINCT *`?

Comment: okay, it does not take the same values and it doesnt repeat them. But the problem is showing just the common values not all of them without repeating